# Which ways are available for a Unity3d program to communicate with other programs?

Tags: networking, unity-game-engine, socket.io, communication

I have Node.js on my computer. I was trying to communicate with Unity using Socket.io. This however seems to be very difficult because of loads of errors and bad examples in projects on github.com

I know you can request websites with the WWW class, but this is too slow if you want to update a position of an object many times a second (please correct me if I am wrong!).

**So I was wandering in which ways (www, [ws://], [ipc://]) can Unity3d communicate with the computer or other programs outside of it's own environment?**

*And maybe which type of communication is already made for Node.js? (since that's the program I am using to control communications from other ip's)*

Answer (score 0):

You are right in assuming that polling(http requests) won't be enough for what you're trying to do.

You can always use C# [sockets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.net.sockets.socket) in async mode but you need to write your own implementation of websockets.

Unity3d doesn't provide a websocket implementation, but you can take a look [here](https://github.com/NetEase/UnitySocketIO) and [here](https://github.com/sta/websocket-sharp). I haven't used any of them so I can't testify to their robustness.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I've seen the first github link you showed me and tried it with no success :( However the second one looks promising so I'll try that as well! Thank you! :)
 But if it doesn't work I would basically have to write my own socket (.dll) to get this working?
ipc;// doesn't exists either then in Unity or C#?

Comment: Unfortunately yes, Unity support for anything else than http is lacking, actually the support for http is also lacking. You don't need to create a dll, you can write C# code without the need to package it in a dll.